# How to cut at the same height

Tags: edit-mode, loop

I want to use the cutting tool add a new edge just above this doorway. I need the tool to cut at exactly the same height all the way around. I don't want to use Ctrl+R as the loop cut cuts other parts of the building too:

[image]

Comment: I think you can achieve this pretty easily by using CTRL+R, but hiding the vertices/faces you don't want to cut before you add the loop cut.

Comment: thanks, how do I use CTRL+R but not get it to cut the whole building at once?

Comment: Added a second solution showing how this works, although Chris's seems to directly address your request to do so with the Knife tool.

Comment: Have a look at the Knife Project Tool. Setup a 2D open shape, align it to the target mesh and the tool will "project" a cut based on the view through your target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Knife tool, set your view to an ortho side view hit "K" for knife than "Z"(cut through) and "C"(constrain) than draw your edge cut.

EDIT:
Another option could be to select these edges and just right click and select subdivide and than slide that edge by double tapping "G" to move it into position. Creating edge loop cuts is usually easier when you don't have Tris though. [image]

Comment: that did it, no need for the z key though, as there is a building behind it. I did
5 - make sure you are in orth mode; 3 front view; 4 - rotate left; K - cut; C constrain; Enter to fix cut; then back to front view with 3; 6 - rotate right; K and C again

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Chris's solution, I think you can achieve this pretty easily with CTRL+R (loop cut), hiding the faces you don't want to cut. Suppose I want to add a vertical loop cut to this cube:

[image]

But I don't want it to go the full length of the cube:

[image]

To avoid this, I can switch into Wireframe view, and select the bottom 4 vertices:

[image]

Hide them by tapping 'H' on my keyboard:

[image]

Then add my loop cut:

[image]

Finally, hitting Alt+H to unHide the hidden vertices, we see that the loop cut only cut the faces that were not hidden:

[image]

Comment: Can I do the inverse of that, Hiding the whole model is difficult, could I just choose to hide everything other than what i have selected?

Comment: Sure. If you tap CTRL+I while in edit mode with some vertices selected, that will Invert your selection. You can then tap H to Hide the "rest" of the model, which you now selected more easily with CTRL+I.